# CURL error in Netbeans PHP

Tags: php, netbeans

> ERROR:Uncaught No CURL support compiled in

I'm using Netbeans PHP IDE, and while running my PHP code I get these errors.

Any suggestions for how I can resolve these error?

Comment: You need to enable CURL extension inside PHP.

Comment: i didn't find the php.ini file in apache/bin

Comment: If possible run the `phpinfo()` inside a PHP file or `php -i` to show from where PHP is loading the configuration files

Comment: i have enabled both files under xampp/php/php_DEVELOPMENT.ini file. After that also its not working..